# Sorting a table by date in asc order

Tags: javascript, sorting, html-table

I am fairly new to javaScript and I'm trying to make a function that get's data from a json file and then stores specific data from the json into a table, once the data has been stored in the table I then want it to be sorted by date (asc)

i have it all working apart from the sorting of the date by asc order, how would I go about doing this... Here is the code than handles displaying and inserting the data into the table

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>List of races</h2>
            <table id="raceList">
   <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th id="raceName">Race Name</th>
                    <th id="Distance">Distance</th>
                    <th id="Date">Date</th>
                    <th id="Details">Details</th>
                </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    
    </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>
```

```html
function ListRaces(arr) {
    var table = document.getElementById("raceList");
   // table.innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var row = table.insertRow(1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  cell1.innerHTML = arr[i].race_name;
  cell2.innerHTML = LengthConverter(arr[i].racedistance);
  cell3.innerHTML = arr[i].date
  
    }
}
```

Example of generated table

[image]